# How can I validate if no user found

Tags: php, wordpress

My select statement works fine if the ID in the WHERE clause finds a match in the db but the problem starts where there's no match. Now I want to first check if it returns anything before I do anything.

I tried to check with COUNT() but it's seems like there's something I am not doing right.

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix."users";
$myID = $data->user->ID;
$check = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name WHERE refID = '$myID'");

if($check > 0){
    $user_ref = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE refID = '$myID'");
echo "
<table>
    <tr>
        <th style='padding: 10px'>Account ID</th>
        <th style='padding: 10px'>Name</th>
        <th style='padding: 10px'>Email</th>
        <th colspan='2'></th>
    </tr>"; foreach( $user_ref as $ref_data) { if($ref_data->ID == 'Not Active'){ echo "
    <tr>
        <td style='padding: 10px'> $ref_data->ID</td>
        <td style='padding: 10px'> $ref_data->user_nicename</td>
        <td style='padding: 10px'> $ref_data->user_email</td>
        <td>
            <form method='post'>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Approve' /> </form>
        </td>

    </tr>";
}
else { echo "
    <tr>
        <td style='padding: 10px'> $ref_data->ID</td>
        <td style='padding: 10px'> $ref_data->user_nicename</td>
        <td style='padding: 10px'> $ref_data->user_email</td>

    </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

if($_POST['submit']) {
  //Update Member Status $status = "Active";
  $where = array('ID' => $ref_data->ID);
  $subs = array('memberStatus' => $status);
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."users";
  $activate = $wpdb->update($table_name, $subs, $where);

  if($activate){
    echo "
    <script>
      alert('Member has been activated');
    </script>";
  }
}
else {
    echo "You currently have no referrals";
}
```

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: You don't need query to check, you should check null for $user_ref. Because query will NULL if no result is found.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `get_results( string $query = null, string $output = OBJECT )` returns an array of objects upon success otherwise it returns `NULL`. You can do something like the following:

```
$check = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name WHERE refID = '$myID'");

if( is_array( $check ) AND count( $check ) ){
   // data found
}
else{
   // data not found
}
```

Let me know how it went.